# Automizing the process of setting up a new server

Tags: linux, automation, build-automation

I'm maintaining the servers of a web game. Whenever we add a new server to our game, I have to configure many environment details and install softwares (for example, testing if some ports of the new machine can be connected from other places, installing mysql-client, pv..., copying the game server files from the other machine, and changing mysql server connection URL) on the new machine.

So my question is "How can I automize the whole process of setting up a new server?" Because most of the works I do are repetitive. I don't want to do this kind of job whenever a new machine comes in.

Is there a tool that allows me to save the state of a linux machine so that next time when we buy a new server, I can copy the state of an old linux machine to the new machine? I think this is one of the ways to automize the process of setting up a new game server.

I've also tried using some *.sh scripts to automize the process. But it's not always possible to get the return value of every command I execute. This is why I come here and ask for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at [Docker](https://www.docker.com), [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com/home), [Cheff](https://www.chef.io) or [Puppet](https://puppetlabs.com)?
In Docker you can build a new container by describing required operations in [docker file](http://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/). And you can easily move container between machines.

Ansible, Cheff and Puppet are systems management automation tools.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you'll find such tool to automatize an **entire** customization process because it's rather difficult to define/obtain a one-size-fit-all linux machine **state**, especially if the customisation includes logical/functional sequences.

But with good scripting you can obtain a possibly more reliable customisation from scratch (rather than copying it from another machine). I'd recommend a higher-level scripting language, tho, IMHO regular bash/zsh/csh scripting is not good/convenient enough. I prefer python, which gives easy access to every cmd's return code, stdout, stderr and with the pexpect module it can drive interactive cmds.

There are tools to handle specific types of customisations (sw package installations, config files), but not all I needed, so I didn't bother and went straight for custom scripts (more work, but total control). Personal preference, tho, others will advise against that.